# React function with multiple params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues trying to use my delete function that calls an API method for removing that selected item from the database.

The API just accepts the page ID, so I've been trying to send the ID to the api.

This is the function that lives in the main container of the app.

```
  deletePage(id) {
    instance.put(`/admin/deletePage/${id}`).then((response) => {
      this.getPages();
      window.location.replace('/')
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

I then pass this function down as a prop to the Dashboard component, where I create another function to handle the delete:

```
  handleDelete(e, id) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.deletePage(id)
  }
```

and finally, my render function:

```
render() {
    const pages = this.props.pages.map((page, i) => {
        return (
        <div key={i}>
        <h2>{page.title}</h2>
        <a href={`/admin/edit-page/${i}`}>Edit</a>
        <button onClick={this.handleDelete(i)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
        )
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
        {pages}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Currently I get this error in console: `e.preventDefault is not a function`

And if I remove the preventDefault line it just causes a constant reload.

Please help. Just trying to delete stuff mwhaha

Comment: You call 'this.handleDelete(i)' and i is not the actual event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a higher order function to do this. Its just a function that return another function.

```
handleDelete(id) {
    return (event)=> {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.props.deletePage(id)
    }
}
```

then call the same way you were doing before

```
 <button onClick={this.handleDelete(i)}>Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's two problems here.

First, the order of `this.handleDelete` params should be reversed: `this.handleDelete(id, e)`. The event object is always supplied last.

Second, `onClick={this.handleDelete(i)}` should be `onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, i)}`. `onClick={this.handleDelete(i)}` assigns the result of calling `this.handleDelete` to `onClick`. You're accidentally calling `this.handleClick` during the render phase when you mean for that function to be called when the user clicks the button.